# How to Update State React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new on React and I try to learn hooks. I have a probably basic problem but I don't understand why. I determined a hooks state but I couldn't update it.

My Code:

```
function Top(props) {

const [URL, setURL] = useState();
const [Category, setCategory] = useState();

const { handleSubmit, handleChange } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {},
    onSubmit: values => {
        clickCrawlButton(values)
    },
});

const clickCrawlButton = (values) => {
        fetch(props.baseURL + "/reddit_top", requestOptionsPost)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            setURL(result) // Why did not it work ?
            props.setInfoText("Crawl Process Started ...")
        }).catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
return (
   <div>
     {URL}
   </div>
);
```

Extra Information:

[image: I printed to console. Code Detail]

[image: State does not update but result has come.]

I printed to console but although state does not update, result printed to console.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: I could not update state, that is the problem.

Comment: check what is coming in result

Comment: @cmracar, are you sure the request didn't crash and `setURL(result)` was called?

Comment: If I determine a value, it stays same. I defined empty and coming result is empty.

Comment: check your browser network, whether API call is triggered or not, also check value in result

Comment: I tried to print 'result' to console. It works but state does not change.

Comment: @cmracar, how you check state changes? If you print `URL` to `console` it will previous state. You must do it in `useEffect`

Comment: console the result and add a screenshot of console,

Comment: You said use useState. I have a func. Where will I use useEffect. I want to change state according to fetch result.

Comment: Can you console the `result`?

Comment: I added console results.

Comment: your result is JSON not string you cant display JSON or object in HTML, in this way !!. also, setURL will only set the value on its next update.

Answer (score 1):

You did mistake when console `Data` after `setData`. `setData` works asyncronous and when you console data , it's not updated yet.

```
//incorrect
setData(result);
console.log("Result data" + Data);
```

You can check `Data` changes in `useEffect` with dependencie.

```
//correct
const clickCrawlButton = (values) => {
    fetch(props.baseURL + "/reddit_top", requestOptionsPost)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        setData(result)
        props.setInfoText("Crawl Process Started ...")
    }).catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}

useEffect(() => {
     console.log("Result data" + Data);
}, [Data])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why but when I tried another project, it works.  I used formik and clickCrawlButton is actually will run in formik onSubmit. Could it be because of that?

Comment: Formik has own initialState and own methods. You don’t need to use useState.